# Atomically INSERT+SELECT or SELECT row (based on UNIQUE column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE StackFunctionID
(
    m_FunctionID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    m_GroupID int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    m_Function varchar(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

GO
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_MakeGroupID ON StackFunctionID AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE StackFunctionID
    SET StackFunctionID.m_GroupID = INSERTED.m_FunctionID
    FROM StackFunctionID
    INNER JOIN INSERTED ON (StackFunctionID.m_FunctionID = INSERTED.m_FunctionID)
END;
```

Now I'm trying to write a query for Sql Server 2008 that will

1. If `m_Function` does not exist, create it, and return `m_FunctionID`, `m_GroupID`
2. If `m_Function` exists, return `m_FunctionID`, `m_GroupID`
3. Perform it atomically

After much trying, this is what worked for the last years:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE(m_FunctionID INT, m_GroupID INT);  -- trash use
DECLARE @dummy1 int;                                      -- trash use
MERGE INTO StackFunctionID WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS Target       -- WITH(HOLDLOCK) for thread safety
USING (VALUES(null)) AS dummy2(dummy3)                    -- syntax requires USING
ON Target.m_Function = @m_Function
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @dummy1 = 0                                -- syntax requires something in 'WHEN MATCHED', which is needed for OUTPUT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(m_Function) VALUES(@m_Function)
OUTPUT inserted.m_FunctionID, inserted.m_GroupID
INTO @Results;                                            -- Having a trigger requires 'INTO'
SELECT * FROM @Results                                    -- Having a trigger requires 'INTO'
```

However, there was a bug: when a row is INSERTED, OUTPUT returns `m_GroupID`=0

Questions:

1. How do I always get correct `m_GroupID` ?
2. Is it possible to achieve the goal with a simpler query? (because current one is really hard to understand with all those "syntax requirements")

Comment: Relying on `UNIQUE m_Function` use `TRY CATCH` to `INSERT` and then `SELECT`.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: That trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assume only 1 row will ever be inserted. It seems that maybe you are trying to fix it with that MERGE? But who knows what your actual question is here.

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity.

Comment: @Serg you should post this as answer

Comment: @SeanLange I fixed it (hopefully). Thanks for pointing out! I never thought about this problem, I'm just the beginner with SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on `UNIQUE m_Function` use `TRY CATCH` to `INSERT` and then `SELECT`. 
Demo

```
CREATE TABLE StackFunctionID
(
    m_FunctionID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    m_GroupID int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    m_Function varchar(256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);
INSERT StackFunctionID(m_Function)
VALUES ('a'), ('b');
SELECT * FROM StackFunctionID;

DECLARE @m_Function varchar(256) = 'a'; 
BEGIN TRY
  INSERT StackFunctionID(m_Function)
  VALUES ( @m_Function);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'Already exists';
END CATCH

SELECT m_FunctionID, m_GroupID 
FROM StackFunctionID
WHERE m_Function = @m_Function;
```